# html input action through button

Tags: html, forms

I am using the following form to take input and then set an action

```
<select name="page_option">
<option value="go1">GO1</option>
<option value="go2">Go 2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Change home.php" />
```

Instead of this I want to have two buttons side by side,one button has text GO1 while other has GO2 and when user click GO1 and GO2 it will serve the same purpose as this above form
Also when Go1 button is clicked the page will display below the buttons "GO1 is on" and when Go2 is clicked it will display below "GO2 is on"

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following..

```
<form action='action.php' method='post'>
<input type="submit" name='go1' value="go1">
<input type="submit" name='go2' value="go2">
```

in action.php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['go1']))
{
  $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Go1 button is on'
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['go2']))
{
  $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Go2 button is on'
}

print_r($_SESSION['msg']);
```

Hope this will help you. You must start session at the beginning of action.php file
Thanks

Comment: Yes it works but
in go1 button code I print "go1 is on" and after clicking on go1 it displays go1 is on but when I again access the same page its not displaying
"go1 is on" will needs to remain there until someone click on go2 button

Comment: You can store that value in session... it will remains same until u update the value

Comment: the session works for a limited time
its not forever 
how can it to be made forever?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="form_action.asp" method="get">
     <select name="page_option">
<option value="go1">GO1</option>
<option value="go2">Go 2</option>
</select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

**action="form_action.asp" method="get"**

Comment: Its giving the same result
I want to display two buttons Go1 and Go2 side by side

Answer (score 0):

You can have two submit buttons, as follows:

```
<input type="submit" value="go1">
<input type="submit" value="go2">
```

You can check serverside which button was clicked, and lead the user to the appropriate page.

Answer (score 0):

then use java script

```
 <input type="submit" onclick="function1()" value="go1">
<input type="submit" onclick="function2()" value="go2">
```

funcation f1(){} 
    funcation f2(){}